What is the preferred / recommended rlang metaprogramming syntax to use on both sides of an assignment operator in the `dplyr::mutate()` function?
I have a question about an issue that's similar to this older question about the dplyr::filter() function, except that my example is a bit more complicated because dplyr::mutate() needs to process variable names on two sides of an assignment operator.
I have a tibble containing multiple columns, a few of which are meant to contain strings.  I'd like to select a subset of column names programmatically from a vector of column names, and use the toupper() function inside of dplyr::mutate() to force capitalization of all values in the dynamically selected columns.
The tricky part is that with a dplyr::mutate() function, I need to use rlang metaprogramming techniques to refer to each column name twice, once on either side of the := assignment operator.
The code sample below shows several alternative syntaxes for doing this; uncommenting each alternative while commenting out the remaining five always leads to the same output result.
library(tidyverse)

# Tibble with columns containing mixed-case strings
tbl <- tibble(first_name=c('fReD', 'Sue', 'nancy'),
              last_name=c('smith', 'Jones', 'jaCKson'),
              age=c(12, 37, 26),
              status=c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE))

# List of column names (potentially but not necessarily present in tibble)
# which contain string values needing to be converted to all capital letters 
allcaps <- c('first_name', 'last_name', 'random_extra_column')

for (cn in colnames(tbl)) {
  if (cn %in% allcaps) {
    # The notation on the left side of the := operator has at least three
    # possible options that accomplish the desired result: {{}}, !!, !!sym().
    # Additionally, the notation on the right side of the := operator has at
    # least two possible options: eval(sym()), get().
    #
    # Thus, there are in total at least six possible combinations.  When
    # uncommented, each of the versions below appears to lead to an equivalent
    # output result.
    #
    # But which of these is actually the best or "preferred" syntax, and why?
    # Are any of these alternatives more robust in other use cases?  Do any of
    # them exhibit subtle differences from the others that would only manifest
    # in specific circumstances?
    tbl <- mutate(tbl, {{cn}} := toupper(eval(sym(cn))))
    #tbl <- mutate(tbl, !!cn := toupper(eval(sym(cn))))
    #tbl <- mutate(tbl, !!sym(cn) := toupper(eval(sym(cn))))
    #tbl <- mutate(tbl, {{cn}} := toupper(get(cn)))
    #tbl <- mutate(tbl, !!cn := toupper(get(cn)))
    #tbl <- mutate(tbl, !!sym(cn) := toupper(get(cn)))
  }
}

# Verify that desired column values are now in all capital letters
print(tbl)

My question: which of these is the best or "preferred" syntax to use in this scenario--and if there is a preferred version, why is it better?

use  :
mutate(tbl, across(all_of(cn),  \(x) toupper(x))) 
that is the preferred way. see vignette("programming") for reference.

Or without the loop: mutate(tbl, across(any_of(allcaps), toupper)

@Ric, @Edward: O.K., I confirm both of these solutions work.  It seems the across() function was the key piece I'd been missing.  Evidently it was introduced over 4 years ago, but I started learning dplyr even earlier than that, and I never realized this updated functionality existed until just now. Thanks, both!
